# GWT: How to run code in the Backend automatically?

Tags: gwt

I understood that GWT apps are separated into Frontend and Backend code.

In the little example that I wrote the Backend operations (XXXServiceImpl) are alwyas triggered by the Frontend (button pressed, etc.).

**Question:** Is there a way to run code in the Backend automatically? An example would be some initialization stuff that's not triggered by the Frontend (preferably it would be only executed once, during startup of the web app).

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the server do not have to be triggered by a user. When your web app launches, it can make a call like `initialize()` to the backend, which will tell your server-side code to run some initialization method once.

If this initialization process is not dependent on a single client instance, you can add a check to see if the initialization has been already done and skip it in this case.

Finally, you can run a simple servlet that you can trigger manually (or using a cron-job, deferred task, etc. - depends on your platform) when you deploy your code. The drawback here is that you have to remember to do it every time a new server instance is started.

Comment: Can you link an example please? What I've done now is to add a call to the backend to a (Async)Service, triggered in the onModuleLoad() method of my app.